# AWS: Query regarding auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have gone through autoscaling documentation but that does not clarify my doubt.

I would like to understand what exactly happens when you add your ec2 instances to the auto scaling group.

When a new instance gets triggered does it just increases the compute capacity of the instance?

Does it just create a clone of the existing instances?

If I have an application running on two instances sharing the same filesystem, how does the 3rd instance which got spun as a part of autoscaling gets added to the existing cluster and how does it scale up the application load?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. It launches additional instance, which you may add behind a load balancer when creating autoscaling group.
2. It will use AMI specified in launch configuration to launch new instances.
3. You need to make sure in AMI is attaching shared file system upon boot. Also, you need to create autoscaling with load balancer to share the load and have your all instances behind a load balancer.

Comment: Thanks kunal but that doesn't answer my question, The points you mentioned i have already gone through. My question is more specific to application scale out, I dont think launch config allows you to attach existing shared disks. If there are two servers in auto scaling group and If an additional instances is getting launched does the new instance will be clone of existing one?If yes, How does the new instance will get auto configured and get added to existing application cluster

Comment: @biz, he seems to have exactly answered your questions.  The new instance is not a clone of an existing one, it is a clone from the AMI specified in the launch configuration, the same AMI that launched the running servers.  Shared *filesystem* != shared *disks*.

Comment: How can you attach the shared disk to an instance which gets auto spinned as a part of autoscaling policy? Whats confusing me is when a brand new vm gets spinned with the ami how does it shares the load of the existing instances